# Finding a lower bound for a fractional part

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, trigonometric-series

I am interested in developing an accurate estimate for the following function:
$$
F(A) = \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t};
$$ here $A=4\pi (3/2)^n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I am aware that $F(A)\ge 0$; I am looking for a *tight* lower bound that is positive for $A$ (or $n$). The sum is convergent by Dirichlet's Test; it is just a matter of obtaining a careful lower bound.

This is part of a larger calculation: I want to show that eventually $E(A)\cdot F(A)>4$, where $E(A)$ is positive and exponential. The case where the series is positive is easy since $E(A)\to\infty$ and if the series is non-negative, $F(A)>1/2$. I'm a bit stuck on the case where the sum is negative. Using Maclaurin series and trig identities, we have
$$
F(A)=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i (\log(1 - e^{i A}) - \log(1-e^{-i A}))}{2\pi}
$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\cot(\pi A))$$
$$=1-\{A\}$$I have tried to use the periodicity of the numerator, since $A=2\pi r, r=R/T\in \mathbb{Q}$ to write $F$ as a double sum. Let $S_v=\sum_{t=1}^T \frac{\sin(A t)}{t+v\cdot T}$: then we have

\begin{align}F(A) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi} \left (\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{\sin(A t)}{t}+\sum_{t=T+1}^{2T}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t}+\sum_{t=2T+1}^{3T}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t}+\cdots \right )\\
= \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{\pi} \left (\sum_{t=1}^T\frac{\sin(A t)}{t}+\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t+T}+\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t+2T}+\cdots \right )\\
=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{v=0}^{\infty} \left (\sum_{t=1}^{T}\frac{\sin(A t)}{t+v\cdot T} \right ) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{v=0}^{\infty}S_v. \end{align}
I believe the $S_v$ alternate in sign and have decreasing magnitudes. One approach might be developing a careful bound for $S_0$ and showing $|S_0|>>|S_1|>>|S_2|>>\cdots$ to provide a lower bound. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x t)}{t}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2\pi}, 0<x<2\pi$ so your expression is just $1-r_0$ where $r_0$ is the fractional part of $r$ (assuming $r$ is not integral)

Comment: @Conrad, my apologies, $A$ does not depend on $t$ but depends on another parameter and in general is not in this range. In fact, $A=A(n)= 4\pi (3/2)^n$; I wasn't sure if including this would make the post unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I see, so basically you want to use the expression for $F(A)$ directly to obtain information about the fractional part of $(3/2)^n$ since you know that $F(A)$ is related to that

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: there is a Russian paper by Dubickas that gives a lower bound for $||(3/2)^k|| \ge (0.5769)^k, k \ge k_0$ (my Russian is iffy but the statement seems to be clear); not sure if that helps - in your case it would give some lower bound $f(A(n)) \ge c^n$ for $c$ related to $0.5769$; http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=4766&option_lang=eng

Comment: @Conrad, many thanks; I have found [an English version](https://tinyurl.com/dubickasenglish) of the same PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\dfrac{\sin Am}m = -\Re\left(i\,\dfrac{e^{iAm}}m\right) = -\Re\dfrac d{dA} \dfrac{e^{iAm}}{m^2},$$
then, applying series representation of the dilogarithm function in the form of
$$S(A)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{iAm}}{m^2}=\operatorname{Li_2}(e^{iA}),$$
[one can get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-re%28d%2FdA%20polylog%20%28e%5E%28i%20A%29%29%29)
$$-\Re S'(A)= -\Im \ln(1-e^{iA}) = -\arg(1-e^{iA}) = -\arg\left(2\cos^2\dfrac A2\left(1-i\tan\dfrac A2\right)\right), $$
$$-\Re S'(A) = \dfrac12(\pi-\operatorname{mod}(A,2\pi)),$$
[image: Testing of Arg]
$$F(A) = \dfrac12-\dfrac1\pi \Re S'(A) =1-\operatorname{frac}\left(\dfrac A{2\pi}\right),$$
where $\operatorname{frac} x = x-\lfloor x\rfloor.$

Therefore, a lower bound of $\;F(A)\;$ is $\;\mathbf 0\;$ at $\;A\to 2k\pi-0,\;$ where $\;k\in\mathbb N.\;$

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'm aware that this is a sawtooth function translated up by $\pi/2$, so the lower bound is zero. What I would like is a tight error bound that depends on $A$.

Comment: @Integrand I hope this task is simplified now.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear with my introduction, but for $A$ real it's clear enough that $F(A)\ge 0$. I don't think your bound is tight enough for what I want, especially given my introduction where I would like to show $E(A)F(A)>4$; if the best we can say is $F(A)=0$, this isn't super helpful.

Comment: @Integrand Then my exact answer means that the task standing should be corrected.